# Wants to display birt report on my website on xhtml page

Tags: birt

As I am new to BIRT topic, I created reports by connecting to my database. Also I integrated Birt Viewer with Tomcat server but still I can't find way like how to display the reports on my webpage. So if someone knows it then give me the steps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the URL when you open a Report in the Web-Viewer. there should be something like  `.../viewer/frameset?foldername/reportname.rptdesign`. Change `frameset` to `run` and it returns a HTML/JavaScript page without the viewer control icons. `.../viewer/run?foldername/reportname.rptdesign`

Now you could use an iframe to embed the target of the URL directly into your html site:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src=".../viewer/run?foldername/reportname.rptdesign"</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks Simulant, it helped me almost but now I m facing problem and that is like I have created two reports which work as master-drill reports. In eclipse, for master report I am asking parameters like store name, to date and for date so that it will give limited output. This is working fine in eclipse, but while I am trying to run from localhost server that is tomcat, parameters are not shown properly. why so ??

Comment: It also showing such error :

org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details: Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile. org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ; java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine the default workspace location. Check your OSGi-less platform configuration of the plugin or datatools workspace path.